# What is the relation between universality and chaotic behavior in Elementary Cellular Automata?

Tags: complexity-theory, computability, cellular-automata

So i know that rule 110 from Elementary Cellular Automata is universal but i am wondering if we had other chaotic behaviors let's say there exists a system that shows nearly infinite chaotic behaviors {a structure at a time} similar to ECA structures, how can we prove or disprove universality from that system ?

Suppose we have a system with one specific rule to execute and the input can be defined by different number of cells {i.e input = 5 cells} these 5 cells for example can show (2000) chaotic behavior... 4 cells can show nearly (1800), for example to get a structure from the (1800) structures, i can change the 4 cells by changing the rule set of these 4 cells just like in ECA => 'two white cells will result in a black cell', i can define a similar rule set on the 4 cells, 5 cells or more generally on x cells where x < infinite.

That system with same input {4 cells} with different rule set can simulate most of the structures in Elementary Cellular Automata like rule 30, 90 & 60 and others, what can be proved about such system and how universality is related to it ?

Comment: You prove (or disprove) universality by proving that the thing can (or cannot) simulate some other universal system.

Comment: Can you define "chaotic behaviors", or what it means for a system to "show nearly infinite chaotic behaviors", in a precise or rigorous way?  If not then you certainly can't prove a result of the form you seem to hope exists.  Personally, I doubt that any such result exists.  There are chaotic systems that are very simple and I doubt are universal.  The question seems to be based on a hope that somehow there is some relationship between chaos vs universality, but I'm skeptical about whether that hope is actually valid.

Answer (score 3):

Chaotic behavior does not seem to imply universality, from what I can see.  I don't see any reason to expect it would.

For instance, here's an example to challenge your intuition that the two concepts are somehow related.  [Wikipedia lists](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chaos_theory) the dynamic system given by the map $x \mapsto 4x (1-x)$ and $y \mapsto x + y \bmod 1$ as an example of a chaotic system.  However I doubt that this system is universal in any meaningful sense.

As [David Richerby wrote](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/48239/what-is-the-relation-between-universality-and-chaotic-behavior-in-elementary-cel#comment98840_48239), the way you prove universality is "by proving that the thing can simulate some other universal system".  I don't think "chaotic behavior" -- whatever that might mean -- is a helpful guide to determining whether a particular system is universal.